# What do the numbers in the end credits mean?

Tags: portal-2

If you look carefully at the Portal 2 end credits (found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVVZaZ8yO6o), spoiler warning), you'll see the following numbers at the top of the screen:

```
2.67
1002
45.6
```

Is there meaning behind these numbers, or are they just random?

Comment: The scrolling stuff to the left of it also seems interesting. I have searched a lot but have found nothing interesting yet so far; the values you found could be an in-game coordinate or angle (but for what level?) or perhaps they are parameters for something... *Will we ever discover?*

Comment: Or, it could be that these numbers can be used as a code to decrypt the scrolling stuff...

Comment: Related thread we can follow along: http://www.facepunch.com/threads/1082375-Portal-2-Ending-Hidden-Code

Comment: There is a BSOD somewhere in the game, perhaps the error there might mean something too...

Comment: For the record, the numbers that appear in the end credits of Co-op Mode are the same as these ones.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On `map sp_a4_finale4`, with `setpos 2.67 1002 45.6` under `sv_cheats 1` (and `noclip`?) you are placed at an interesting position. You are placed between GLaDOS and the stalemate resolution button, properly between the beginning of the lines. So the coordinates could be taken from where *the dragging animation starts* if I'm not mistaken...
<sub>I haven't checked all levels as I don't have time for that at the moment.</sub>

Go ahead and check the location; but perhaps, there might be more meaning to these coordinates.

Thinking about the connection between the song and that location, it does refer to the location where that she gets back in control of the Aperture Science Enrichment Center...

Comment: I may be dumb, but I don't see where that solution comes from...

Comment: I don't understand how they got there either, don't want to create a one-time use account either to ask. But [it has been discovered before](http://topsy.com/s?q=be+sure+to+drink+your+ovaltine) too, some Steam threads found on Google when combining that sentence with Portal 2 also mention that this has been found in the early leaked Portal 2 ending credits song... Perhaps it's a known technique that can be found in the ARG thread?

Comment: Accepted for the intriguing coordinate position, but I don't buy into the whole ovaltine bit. That seems to be more of an internet meme than a real easter egg.

Comment: It's Facepunch. I used to be a member there, and I read through the thread a bit. They made the Ovaltine bit up.

Comment: @TomWijsman - It seems the Youtube link has gone dead

Comment: @Robotnik: Seems like a temporary error to me. Anyhow, it was false information. Removed.

Comment: I have no idea what this means or which game this is, but this answer sounds intelligent so upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The ovaltine thing on facepunch is a joke related to a [penny-arcade strip](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/6/20/) from a few months ago. I think the coordinates thing is a good lead, but we haven't been able to solve the mystery of the scrolling bit.